# How is serialVersionUID serialized in Java?

Tags: java, class, static, serializable, serialversionuid

Class members (static) cannot be serialized. The reason is obvious - they are not held by the object(s) of the class. Since they are associated with the class (rather than the object of that class), they are stored separately from the object.

`serialVersionUID` is declared as a static field within a class that implements the [`java.io.Serializable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) interface something like the following.

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
```

It is used as a version control in a `Serializable` class. If it is not explicitly declared, will be done automatically by JVM, based on various aspects of the `Serializable` class, as described by [the Java(TM) Object Serialization Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html).

If it is not explicitly declared within the class implementing the `Serializable` interface  then a warning may issue.

> The serializable class `SomeClass` does not declare a `static` `final`
>   `serialVersionUID` field of type `long`

Is it serialized even though it is `static`, how or is it an exception to serialization?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Serialization is done "magically," with lots of reflection, and has all sorts of special behavior -- including e.g. looking up the *static* `serialVersionUID` of the class.

Comment: +1 `serialVersionUID`  has a special purpose for Java Serialization and may be generated dynamically if not set.  Note: some serializations ignore it.

Comment: @PeterLawrey : You must have a detailed answer on this question I believe.

Comment: @Tiny Serialization treats this fields specially based on the specification.  Note: most people hard code this to something like 1 and other serialization formats ignore it.  It is one of things which seemed like a good idea at the time but is usually more trouble than it is worth.

Answer (score 2):

The `serialVersionUID` itself is not serialized. At least, not in the same way as the other properties of your object. Instead it is written out to your output destination as part of a special 'header' that contains information required to rebuild the objects being written.

Comment: where can i read more about this, because i took a look at the documentation but such thing didn't appear?

Answer (score 2):

Let me clear you the use of `serialVersionUID` while writing and reading objects to/from file.

In below code, I have written two functions `writeObject()` and `readObj()`

`writeObject()` is for writing the object in file

`readObj()` is for reading the Object from file

```
package com.msq;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class A implements Serializable{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    int a;
    transient int b;

    public int getA() {
        return a;
    }
    public void setA(int a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
    public int getB() {
        return b;
    }
    public void setB(int b) {
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

```
package com.msq;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class B implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 123L ;
    /**
     * 
     */
    String name;
    A a;

    public B() {

    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public A getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public void setA(A a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //writeObject();
        readObj();
    }

    static void writeObject() {
        B b = new B();
        b.setName("Musaddique");
        A a2 = new A();
        a2.setA(5);
        a2.setB(10);
        b.setA(a2);
        ObjectOutputStream write = null;

        try {
            write = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(
                    "D:\\serObj.bat"));
            write.writeObject(b);
            write.flush();
            write.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    static void readObj() {
        ObjectInputStream reader = null;

        try {
            reader = new ObjectInputStream(
                    new FileInputStream("D:\\serObj.bat"));
            B b1 = (B) reader.readObject();
            System.out.println("name: "+b1.getName());
            System.out.println("value of a: "+b1.getA().getA());
            System.out.println("value of b: "+b1.getA().getB());
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here I have used `serialVersionUID = 123L` for class B and `serialVersionUID = 1L` for class A and also used `transient` keyword for variable b in order to restrict to save the value of b into file.

1) Write data to file then read the file you will get following output

```
name: Musaddique
value of a: 5
value of b: 0
```

you wil get value of b: 0 because we have used transient for b.

Now for testing try to write object by the same call but while reading change the `serialVersionUID = 765L` then u will get below exception

```
java.io.InvalidClassException: com.msq.B; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 123, local class serialVersionUID = 765
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at com.msq.B.readObj(B.java:81)
    at com.msq.B.main(B.java:46)
```

So, it is necessary to use same `serialVersionUID` while reading and writing the object from file.

Also, it is used in RMI calls when you in-corporate classes from one machine to another machine or system.

Answer (score 1):

Think of `serialVersionUID` not as part of the object data being serialized but as part of the class description. The same way that the class name is part of the serialization stream. Full details of the stream format are documented at [Grammar for the Stream Format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/protocol.html#10258).