# Importance of serialVersionId in Serialization?

Tags: java

Whenever we try to `serialize` an object of a Class, we always have a unique value for `serialVersionId` as a private final field, what is its significance with respect to `deserialization`, can we use it to check whether the object and the values have been deserialized in a proper way ?

Comment: Oh..sorry..thanks for the refrence..

Comment: See also [How is serialVersionUID serialized in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13918997/1037210)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is used to check whether the same class definition was used for Serialization as well as DeSerialization. Straight from the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html)

> The serialization runtime associates with each serializable class a version number, called a serialVersionUID, which is used during deserialization to verify that the sender and receiver of a serialized object have loaded classes for that object that are compatible with respect to serialization. If the receiver has loaded a class for the object that has a different serialVersionUID than that of the corresponding sender's class, then deserialization will result in an InvalidClassException. A serializable class can declare its own serialVersionUID explicitly by declaring a field named "serialVersionUID" that must be static, final, and of type long:
>
> ANY-ACCESS-MODIFIER static final long serialVersionUID = 42L;
>
> If a serializable class does not explicitly declare a serialVersionUID, then the serialization runtime will calculate a default serialVersionUID value for that class based on various aspects of the class, as described in the Java(TM) Object Serialization Specification. However, it is strongly recommended that all serializable classes explicitly declare serialVersionUID values, since the default serialVersionUID computation is highly sensitive to class details that may vary depending on compiler implementations, and can thus result in unexpected InvalidClassExceptions during deserialization. Therefore, to guarantee a consistent serialVersionUID value across different java compiler implementations, a serializable class must declare an explicit serialVersionUID value. It is also strongly advised that explicit serialVersionUID declarations use the private modifier where possible, since such declarations apply only to the immediately declaring class--serialVersionUID fields are not useful as inherited members.

Also , check Josh Bloch's book Effective Java (2nd Edition):

> **the automatically-generated UID is generated based on a class name, implemented interfaces, and all public and protected members. Changing any of these in any way will change the serialVersionUID. So you don't need to mess with them only if you are certain that no more than one version of the class will ever be serialized (either across processes or retrieved from storage at a later time).**
>
> If you ignore them for now, and find later that you need to change the class in some way but maintain compatibility w/ old version of the class, you can use the JDK tool serialver to generate the serialVersionUID on the old class, and explicitly set that on the new class. (Depending on your changes you may need to also implement custom serialization by adding writeObject and readObject methods - see Serializable javadoc or aforementioned chapter 11.)

Comment: upvote, it was informative :)

Comment: This is almost same as answer of Jon Skeet  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285793/what-is-a-serialversionuid-and-why-should-i-use-it

Comment: If we are creating a Custom Class and implementing Serializable , if we give our own id. how will the receiver come to know about this class based on id in some other machine?

Comment: `serialVersionUID` gets serialized along with the object. Moreover the class definition should be present in the remote machine for de serialization.

Answer (score 0):

It is important when you serialize and de-serialize the same class using *different VMs* or on *different machines*. The UID is used to check, if the class you are trying to de-serialize is the really the one you think it is, so if your class in your code has one UID, and the class that was serialized has a different one, the de-serialization will fail.

A class without a UID will be given one automatically by the JVM, but there is no guarantee that different JVMs will give the same UID to the same class.

You can also refer this, which I found from SO:

[What is a serialVersionUID and why should I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285793/what-is-a-serialversionuid-and-why-should-i-use-it)
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html

Answer (score 0):

From the doc of [Serializable Object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html)

> The serialization runtime associates with each serializable class a
> version number, called a serialVersionUID, which is used during
> deserialization to verify that the sender and receiver of a serialized
> object have loaded classes for that object that are compatible with
> respect to serialization. If the receiver has loaded a class for the
> object that has a different serialVersionUID than that of the
> corresponding sender's class, then deserialization will result in an
> InvalidClassException. A serializable class can declare its own
> serialVersionUID explicitly by declaring a field named
> "serialVersionUID" that must be static, final, and of type long:
>
> ANY-ACCESS-MODIFIER static final long serialVersionUID = 42L;
>
> If a
> serializable class does not explicitly declare a serialVersionUID,
> then the serialization runtime will calculate a default
> serialVersionUID value for that class based on various aspects of the
> class, as described in the Java(TM) Object Serialization
> Specification. However, it is strongly recommended that all
> serializable classes explicitly declare serialVersionUID values, since
> the default serialVersionUID computation is highly sensitive to class
> details that may vary depending on compiler implementations, and can
> thus result in unexpected InvalidClassExceptions during
> deserialization. Therefore, to guarantee a consistent serialVersionUID
> value across different java compiler implementations, a serializable
> class must declare an explicit serialVersionUID value. It is also
> strongly advised that explicit serialVersionUID declarations use the
> private modifier where possible, since such declarations apply only to
> the immediately declaring class--serialVersionUID fields are not
> useful as inherited members. Array classes cannot declare an explicit
> serialVersionUID, so they always have the default computed value, but
> the requirement for matching serialVersionUID values is waived for
> array classes.

There is a similar Thread. Check this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285793/what-is-a-serialversionuid-and-why-should-i-use-it)

Comment: This is same as answer of Jon Skeet  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285793/what-is-a-serialversionuid-and-why-should-i-use-it

Comment: @ManishDoshi yup later found it and marked the question as duplicated. Anyways it is same as the doc not the same of that thread :p